# creating pdf with html and upload to firebase storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

i would like to create a cloud function for creating pdf's from newly created firestore documents. i am doing similar thing on my electron app but it uses electron things. anyway. i have a html template that needs to convert pdf and upload to the firebase storage. i looked for some examples but nothing helped me.

i tried this for now and its very close  to what i want: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48539716/11248482

there is a library called pdfkit but it does not use html for creating pdf files so didn't help me. do you have any idea how can i do that in cloud functions?

Comment: Like raw html? you dont have javascript or python at least?

Comment: its raw html with little css... i need this because of create pdf template nothing else